# How insert number (double) in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I use this code

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/price_for_liter_value_edit_text"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:textColor="@color/dn_14_date"
     android:fontFamily="sans-serif-regular"
     android:textSize="18sp"
     android:text=""
     android:padding="4dp"
     android:inputType="number"/>
```

and at this line I set inputType:

```
  android:inputType="number"
```

but I cant enter double number (with . - like as 1.3 or 20.5). 
**What type should I use in inputFormat ?**

Comment: Use `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`.

Comment: @PG_Android Both solutions will work.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use

```
  android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Answer (score 11):

You can see this [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#TextView_inputType) for all variations of allowed inputType. In your case

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

or

```
int type = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER |  InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL;

((EditText)findViewById(R.id.price_for_liter_value_edit_text)).setInputType(type);
```

Answer (score 6):

For Edittext, there is an attribute **digits** :-

```
 android:digits="0123456789."
```

If this param is set, specifies that this TextView has a numeric input method 
     and that these specific characters are the ones that it will 
     accept. [string] - **Text snippet from developer.android.com**

This will allow only numbers and "." to be added in the textview

Comment: that need to be as solved solution, because if you put `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` or `android:inputType="number"` and `android:digits="0123456789"` without "." you will not be able to insert a point into your EditText.

Like that need to be
`android:inputType="numberDecimal"`
`android:digits="0123456789."`